# Inner workings of an elastic search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I want to learn how elasticsearch works. I got concerns about scalability of my design. I have got 50 million documents. Every document has got around 50 string properties,45 integer properties and 5 datetime properties.

So my concerns are When I query ES with a predicate containing 8 fields with 3 sortings based on date and integer values. How does ES perform? What happens in the background so I ensure the performance when system reaches 500 million?

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/distributed-search.html

Answer (score 1):

The link [blackpop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3090380/blackpop) provided in the comment is a good start to understand whats going on. But you don't need to understand everything to make things work. The good thing on elasticsearch is - it's *elastic*. Meaning, it *scales very well*, so if you need more performance you just add more RAM/CPU/Server and maybe config a cluster (well, at least *then* you should learn something about shards and nodes).

Btw, your scenario seems not to be very hard task for lucene (on which ES is based), if you need performing queries under a second or so. We use similiar settings with > 200 M docs on one lone middle range server (around 2500 euro). I would encourage you to make real live tests on your desktop/laptop indexing 50 M dox. We did this, too.